# What is non-derogatory way of saying "people here are obsessed with sports"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nonsubjective

Saying obsessed or being crazy about something seems a little negative and derogatory. How am I supposed to say it in a positive way.

Comment: How is 'obsessed' derogatory? It might be considered extreme, but derogatory is not the same thing.

Comment: @Mitch: people who are obsessed are mentally ill; ergo, "obsessed" is a negative term and _deprecatory_.

Comment: @BillFranke: _Derogatory_ doesn't encompass all negative things. _Ugly_ is not a derogatory term; it is very negative, just not derogatory.

Comment: @Mitch: Why do you use _derogatory_ when I used _[deprecatory](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deprecate)_? Just because they're sometimes synonyms doesn't mean they're fungible. They have nuances. Tell somebody they're ugly and then ask them if they think it's derogatory or just an expression of your negative opinion about their looks. And then try to explain that you weren't being derogatory, only negative and totally honest. Hope they're not bigger than you are.

Comment: How is calling someone ugly NOT derogatory? My dictionary defines "derogatory" as "tending to detract or belittle; intentionally offensive". I would think that saying someone is ugly "tends to belittle".

Comment: @BillFranke: I used _derogatory_ because that is the word the OP used, and what I used in the comment that you responded to.

Comment: @Jay, BillFranke: epithets are inherently derogatory (and similarly deprecatory). But 'obsessed' is not inherently so ('ugly' I'll grant is arguable; it is often used in derogatory situations, but I don't find it inherently derogatory). Many negative words are easily used in derogatory circumstances, 'obsessed' needs more specific  context to be interpreted as derogatory.

Comment: @Mitch: Context is always crucial.

Comment: @BillFranke: so then you agree with my very first point since there is not enough context in the OP to make 'obsessed' be derogatory. Obsession with sports is not usually considered a mental illness.

Comment: @Mitch: I don't know what the context is. I don't know who the OP is talking about communicating this negative comment to or even how: orally or in writing. He's obviously negative about their being sports nuts, so he wants a totally neutral way of saying it. That's why I suggested "sports enthusiasts". It's like calling computer techs & programmers "geeks" without the weird word, even though "geek" & "nerd" are now honorifics because they've become so socially & economically important -- and rich (a few). "Mental illness", no, intellectual vacuity, yes. YMMV: sorry about that.

Comment: Sports fans I know would consider "obsessed" to be a compliment.  It shows that we know they care about what happens..

Comment: 'Obsessed' is polysemous (a medical meaning and a non medical one) and not truly derogatory in the current sense.  At least not in North America, where it is common slang.  It's much like saying something is 'depressing.'  It does not generally mean 'liable to cause clinical depression.'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say,

> "People here are complete [fanatics](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fanatic?s=t)!"

There is some debate about whether "fan," which is what sports enthusiasts are normally called, is short for "fanatic," (See NB below); however, fanatic, in full form, in the context of sports, means something much stronger. For example, you would call someone who lacks passion for their team a "[fair weather fan](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-fairweather-fan.htm)" but not a "fair weather fanatic." Fanatic has the added punch of zealotry.

Plus, you should not confuse a Phillies fan:

[image]

with the Phillies Phanatic:

[image]

NB: There is a passage in the *[Dickson Baseball Dictionary](http://books.google.es/books?id=ceeU7xSLw5kC&pg=PA307&dq=%22The%20fancy%22%20Dickson%20baseball%20dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SR3GUMbVKYrXqAHC_oDoAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22The%20fancy%22%20Dickson%20baseball%20dictionary&f=false)* which claims that "fan" comes from "the fancy," an archaic expression that referred to dapper young men in the know who were prizefighting enthusiasts. Dickson writes,

> "'The fancy' was long a class in England and America for followers of boxing. Baseball borrowed it and shortened it to 'the fance,' 'fans,' and 'fan.' I do not agree with [Ted Sullivan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Sullivan_%28baseball%29)...that he originated it ['fan'] as an abbreviation of 'fanatic.'"

Whether Dickson is right that Sullivan or anyone else for that matter did not derive "fan" from "fanatic," turning up a reference to baseball enthusiasts as members of "[the fancy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=the%20fancy&searchmode=none)" on the internet is difficult.

Comment: Did you just say that *fanatic* is short for *fan*, not the other way around?

Comment: I meant the other way around.

Comment: There's some debate whether "fan" is short for "fanatic". http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=fan&searchmode=none I saw a reference years ago that said "fan" was derived from "fancyman", and that Etymonline entry seems to be saying something similar. Not that this changes the point of the post, just a side note.

Comment: @Jay: I see that note about boxing fans being called _the fancy_, and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan_(person)) references it too. The closest I've ever heard "fancy" come to "fan" is in, "Fancy a beer?" or the like. Searches for "the fancy" with "baseball" produce nothing except for snippets from the wikipedia source. I am curious to see it used in print, other than that single source.

Comment: There is a phrase that is used for distinction: "Be a fan, not a fanatic."  It's often stated in rules concerning sportsmanship.
Here is an example: http://www.iahsaa.org/resource_center/Character_Sportsmanship_Safety/Conduct_Counts_Full_Color_Poster.pdf

Comment: @tylerharms Almost all of the question I have asked on this forum since joining 2 weeks back, have had one reference of baseball. and I am a Giants man so it makes is easier :)

Comment: @MichealCorleone: Well, it's a good time to be a Giants fan, says Red Sox fan.

Comment: @tylerharms re "fancy" and "the fancy", in the UK pigeon keepers are known as pigeon fanciers and the hobby is know as "the fancy". (Not to be confused with "fancy pigeons", which are a type of bird.)

Comment: @tylerharms "Fancy" is a somewhat obscure verb meaning to like something. Like, "I fancy green shirts." It can also be a noun meaning the act of liking: "I have a fancy for green shirts." People who are interested in a hobby or the like are called "fanciers" -- see DaveP's comment. I think it's a set of words that's largely fallen out of use, but you still here it now and then. Examples: http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20121210160830AAQoegZ http://myfancyforfood.com/ etc

Comment: @DaveP: Thanks for that. I have been searching for instances of "the fancy's" use in sports but have so far come up empty. The Dickson references a newspaperman named Pierce Egan who traced the origins of "fan". Egan was a sports slang historian, and it seems fitting that there are hardly any references to "the fancy" in print, as it was taken from the lexicon of "vagabonds, jailbirds, bartenders, soldiers, and actors."

Answer (score 6):

Any *sports nut* will not mind being called that. In fact, such people usually wear the term as a badge of honor.

For example, look at [the title](http://www.slate.com/articles/sports/sports_nut.html) of this whole section on *Slate Magazine*.

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty colloquial, but you could say that people in that region are "really into" sports "in a big way."

Answer (score 5):

You can call sports nuts *sports enthusiasts* and be neutrally negative. You don't get nastily negative until you use words like *sports crazies*, *sports zealots*, *sportsophages* (analogous to the Harry Potter *Death Eaters*), *sportophagous assholes*, *athleticophagous*, or ***homoludditicus neanderthalensis*** (my own neologism based on the term *[homo ludens](http://ludens.cl/dummies.html)*: *homo* means *human* and *ludens*  means *playing*; [from Latin: "*ludus — from ludere, covers the whole field of play*"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_Ludens_%28book%29), *[Luddite](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/luddite)*, and *[Neanderthal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neanderthal)*